# lstlisting - line number gaps

Tags: listings, line-numbering

Is it possible to add non-number characters on the left of a code block?

Specifically, I want to add `...` to correspond with some source code (see image).

[image]

I am currently using commands to stop / start the line numbers.
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 20mm, top = 30mm, bottom = 25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codebackground}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.92}

\lstset
{
    frame            = tb, % hrule above and below
    keepspaces       = true,
    columns          = flexible,
    basicstyle       = {\normalsize\ttfamily},
    escapeinside     = {(*@}{@*)}, % for escaping
    backgroundcolor  = \color{codebackground},
    showstringspaces = false,
    language         = C,
    keywordstyle     = \color{blue},
    stringstyle      = \color{red},
    commentstyle     = \color{teal},
    numbers          = left, % {none, left, right}
    firstnumber      = 1,
    numberstyle      = \scriptsize\color{black},
    numbersep        = 5pt
}

\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
% for stopping line numbers
\newcommand*\stopnumber
{
    \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}
    {
        \let\thelstnumber\relax
        \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax
    }
}
% for starting line numbers
\newcommand*\startnumber[1]
{
    \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}
    \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}
    {
        \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber
        \refstepcounter{lstnumber}
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber = 456]
int third_function(const int c)
{
    /* error checking */
    if(c < 0)
    {
        return;
    } (*@ \stopnumber @*)

    ...
    (*@ \startnumber{512} @*)
    /* other stuff */
    int d = 4;
    char* word = "third function"; (*@ \stopnumber @*)

    ...
    (*@ \startnumber{678} @*)
    return (c * d);
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple solution that makes use of the `mathescape` option to modify the counter and printing of line numbers. You could also use `escapeinside` if you want to use different escape characters than the standard `$...$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, language=c, numbers=left}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@lstnumber=\thelstnumber

\newcommand\lstsetnumber[1]{\gdef\thelstnumber{#1}}
\newcommand\lstresetnumber{\global\let\thelstnumber=\orig@lstnumber}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=100, mathescape=true]
int foo(int x) {
    // some code$\lstsetnumber{\ldots}$
    ...$\lstresetnumber\setcounter{lstnumber}{199}$

    // more code with extra spacing$\lstsetnumber{}$
    $\lstsetnumber{\ldots}$
    ...$\lstsetnumber{}$
    $\lstresetnumber\setcounter{lstnumber}{299}$

    return x;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\lstsetnumber` macro redefines the output macro for line numbers, in the above example to the fixed value `\ldots`. `\lstresetnumber` resets the output to the standard definition.

Note that you have to subtract 1 from the next line number if you modify the line counter via `\setcounter{lstnumber}` as `listings` automatically increases the counter on the next line.

The code for adding extra empty lines is a bit clumsy, not sure how to add vertical space in a more flexible way here.

Comment: I have updated the question to show what approach I am using, as this method uses `mathescape`

Answer (score 5):

So here's another, easier to use approach that is syntactically the same as in your example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 20mm, top = 30mm, bottom = 25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{codebackground}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.92}
\lstset{ ... }

\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter

\renewcommand\thelstnumber{%
    \ifnum\value{lstnumber}>0
        \origthelstnumber
    \else
        \ifnum\value{lstnumber}=-1
            \ldots
        \fi
    \fi
}

% for starting line numbers
\newcommand*\startnumber[1]{%
    \setcounter{lstnumber}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
}

% for stopping line numbers
\newcommand*\stopnumber{%
    \startnumber{-2}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber = 456]
int third_function(const int c)
{
    /* error checking */
    if(c < 0)
    {
        return;
    } (*@ \stopnumber @*)

    ...
    (*@ \startnumber{512} @*)
    /* other stuff */
    int d = 4;
    char* word = "third function"; (*@ \stopnumber @*)

    ...
    (*@ \startnumber{678} @*)
    return (c * d);
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In your code you are using `\lst@AddToHook` multiple times to change `\thelstnumber`. This is a bit problematic because adding hooks is accumulative, i.e. it adds the same commands everytime you use it. Also, the `listings` documentation explicitly doesn't guarantee that the order of hook execution is the same as the order of definition.

My approach is based on redefining `\thelstnumber` only once and (mis)using negative line numbers for the ellipses in your code. Positive numbers are printed as usual, -1 denotes `\ldots`, other negative numbers don't yield any output at all. So in `\stopnumbers` we just init `lstnumber` with -2 to map the following sequence of -2, -1, 0 to empty, `\ldots`, empty.

In case you'd want a short ellipsis without empty lines around, you could define a new command that inits `lstnumber` with -1.